# How to call sql command in php without submitting a form?

Tags: php, sql

I want to execute sql command such as

```
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
```

in php. But the only way I can find to trigger php event is to submit a form using:

```
if(isset$POST['submit']) {
    $query_run = mysql_query($query);
}
```

But this would refresh the page and wipe off every thing that dynamically created on the page.

What I want is to have a button, press which to trigger sql commands without reloading the page like `onclick` in js. However, sql command cannot be run inside js function (as I can find).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, it helps a lot. I've just replaced the old code with PDO. So, I can use PDO inside js now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is parsed server side which means you can't have it run code without making a server request. Once the page is delivered to the client any php parsing is complete.

You can create a button or link that will send off an http request through javascript, an AJAX call, to a small php script that does the database work you want done. You wouldn't have it call your whole page again. The output from this gets returned to the javascript and can be used to update a CSS block element with success or failure notices.

Here's the W3C Ajax tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is an AJAX call. This requires Javascript (preferably with the help of a library such as jQuery) to assemble the date from the page, make the call to the PHP page, and to present the results onto the page.